# Disable multiple scheduled tasks - PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on a script that disables multiple Scheduled Tasks in Windows 10. This is my attempt:

```
$TasksToDisable = @(
    ""
    ""
    ""
    )

Foreach ($Task in $TasksToDisable) {
    Get-ScheduledTask $Task | Disable-ScheduledTask
}
```

It gives me an error when a scheduled task does not exist.

How to solve this? (without SilentlyContinue)

Thank you! :D

Comment: without knowing the error message its difficult to gauge. Maybe build a **try catch** method within your **ForEach** loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is missing the **-TaskPath** or **-TaskName**

**Example -TaskName**

```
Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "SystemScan"
```

**Example -TaskPath**

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\UpdateTasks\" | Disable-ScheduledTask
```

**Microsoft Disable-ScheduledTask** Webpage
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/disable-scheduledtask?view=windowsserver2019-ps

Maybe your hash list of names is missing slashes in-between.

**Example Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath List**

```
$tasks = Get-ScheduledTask | Select TaskPath | Where {($_.TaskPath -like "*Active Directory Rights Management Services Client*")}
$tasks

ForEach($task in $tasks){

Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "$task" | Disable-ScheduledTask

}
```

**Example Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName List**

```
$tasks = Get-ScheduledTask | Select TaskName | Where {($_.TaskName -like "*AD*")}
$tasks

ForEach($task in $tasks){

Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$task"

}
```

Comment: @NewTheNerd Thank you!  This what i'm looking for!